# Detect Responsible variable for a Java Exception

Tags: java, exception, fault

I have a set of Java programs that are getting some runtime exceptions. I wanted to know if there is an automated mechanism to identify the culprit variable that is responsible for an exception.

For example:

```
public int multiply(String x, String y){
    return Integer.parseInt(x) * Integer.parseInt(y);
}
```

When you call `multiply("4","ab")`, then at runtime, we will get a `NumberFormatException`. Is there any automated process to identify that variable `y` has caused/is responsible for this exception?

Edit1:

After receiving several suggestion from wonderful developers, I am thinking that it cannot be solved at the code level, rather I should do something in the Java compiler. Does anyone has any thought about changing the Java compiler that might help in such cases?

Even if it is not possible in the compiler, can anyone give suggestion about the changes in JVM?

Comment: The compiler will catch that you can't use `*` between an `int` and a `String`.

Comment: The exception will contain the line number it was thrown on and a useful stacktrace. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Well with you example it's overly obvious that y is the culprit. So either improve your functions or use detective work on catching an exception in the function i.e. use try and catches on dodgy bits of code, if you catch an exception check variables that are most likely the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I guess I need to edit my question a little bit more. The whole point is if I am getting an exception at runtime, then how to track the responsible variable.

Comment: You could use a neural network for this, but the idea there is instrument the code and try to detect a pattern, not run static analysis to check for possible null-dereferences (or similar).

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: Can you give more details about what you are thinking that I can do. It's not very clear how to create neural network. Or, how and what pattern I should detect.

Comment: In this instance you could use regular expressions or use try and catches testing both variables, this should be done prior to the return statement

Comment: @PurityLake: Can you give a little more description about your approach. I dont understand what kind of regular expressions I should create. May be try catch could be useful but still it does not give the responsible variable.

Comment: @user2456636 inputs are features from the different inputs to the method, the only output is whether or not you got an exception. That lets you (hopefully, if you have enough training data) predict whether or not you'll get an exception. From there, when you get a real exception, you could try replacing your inputs with known good values, trying to look for which one likely caused the exception. This would really only work for null, format, and possibly type cases. It's not going to catch IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 2):

*Update:*

> I am thinking that it cannot be solved at the code level, rather I should do something in the Java compiler.

By definition `RuntimeException`s cannot be detected by the compiler, they can only be caught and handled while the program is executing.  This can *only* be solved at "at the code level".

> Even if it is not possible in the compiler, can anyone give suggestion about the changes in JVM?

Despite my best efforts you're insisting on going down this path, so I will try to explain what you would have to do.  Understand however that a) this is incredibly complicated and b) almost surely not the correct fix.  *Fix your code, not the JVM*.

You would essentially need to redesign the [Java bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) to contain the additional context you need, and change and [compile the JDK from source](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/29/building-the-jdk.html).  This is theoretically possible, as Java is open source, but would be a heroic undertaking.  There is no "give me more information" flag you can pass the JVM out of the box; here is the list of [JVM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

---

*Real answer starts here:*

It depends on what you mean by "automated".  To my knowledge there's no way to inspect an exception to determine which variable caused the error (I wish it were true for NPEs, would be very helpful).  But you can improve your code to make this more clear.

**Step through your program with a debugger**

Before we get into automation, one option is to [use the Java debugger](https://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse%20debugger%20tutorial) to step through your code line by line and see exactly which point the failure occurs.  This is a highly manual process, but can help you hunt down hard to understand failures.

**Split the exceptional calls into separate lines**

The stack trace does provide the associated line number, so if you change your method to:

```
public int multiply(String x, String y){
  int intX = Integer.parseInt(x);
  int intY = Integer.parseInt(y);
  return intX * intY;
}
```

Then the `NumberFormatException` will now occur on either the first or second line of this function, letting you see which line caused the error.

**Raise a wrapper exception with more context**

Line numbers aren't the most informative though, we can do better by raising our own exception:

```
private int parseIntMsg(String num, String desc)
      throws IllegalArgumentException {
  try {
    return Integer.parseInt(num);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Failed to parse "+desc+"; was '"+num+"'", e);
  }
}

public int multiply(String x, String y) {
  return parseIntMsg(x, "x") * parseIntMsg(y, "y");
}
```

This would now raise a much clearer `IllegalArgumentException` with the message `Failed to parse x; was 'ab'`.

**Do your sanity checks before calling this method**

What's really going on here though is you're not handling this error case at the right time.  Instead, do your sanity checks early, and handle them explicitly.  You're reading in a String from a user?  Check it's a number explicitly, and hand it back to the user to correct if it's not, rather than waiting til you're in the belly of your code and passing around strings that may or may not be valid integers.  Really, you should have no use for this `multiply(String, String)` method you've defined.  Instead, parse your input explicitly into the types you want to work with, then work with them explicitly after verifying the parse succeeded.  See [Why is it good to split a program into multiple classes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154228/why-is-it-good-to-split-a-program-into-multiple-classes) for more thoughts on the subject.

---

Also look into using [`Preconditions`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) from the excellent Guava library; these utility methods let you add lots of rich error messages and expectations about what's going on when your code fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some interceptor that can print input params after the exception. For example you can use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for this case. Here's an example of how to do this [AspectJ-catch-handle-exception](http://www.coderanch.com/t/561286/aop/AspectJ-catch-handle-exception-aspectJ).

Answer (score 0):

For your example what you could do is:

```
public int multiply(String x, String y){
    if (!x.matches("(\d+|\d*\.\d+)")) {
        // give out that x is not a number
    } else if (!y..matches("(\d+|\d*\.\d+)")) {
        // give out thaqt y is not a number
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(x) * Integer.parseInt(y);
    }
}
```

Really the best thing to do with exceptions is to control when they happen. Even if a functions you are using throws an exception, be sure that it is your code that decides whether or not to report this.

There can be cases where an exception is acceptable and you can mention it in the logs and let the code continue or else you stop the flow and mention why you are doing so, as not to cause confusing on a poor unsuspecting user.

Comment: Thanks for the regular expressions. I understand this. But I need a general approach. The code I presented is just an example. With your approach, I cannot put regular expression in all my 1000s of methods.

Comment: +1 for "be sure that it is your code that decides whether or not to report this". Most of the times it is up to the coder to handle exceptions, whether to catch them and ignore or log and terminate.

Comment: Why define a regular expression (and your current pattern incorrectly matches positive real numbers, not integers) rather than just catching the `NumberFormatException`s individually?

Comment: @dimo414 The OP wants to know which variable is the cause of the exception

Comment: And your regular expressions will not do this.  Calling `multiply("-5","10.4")` will report that `x` is the problem, when in fact if allowed to continue `y` would be.  Furthermore, even if you correct the regular expression to actually match mathematical integers (`-?\d+`), you cannot (easily) ensure these numbers are in the valid range for a Java `int`.